# Cannot run compiled c program when in Desktop virtualization Citrix

Tags: c, gcc, solaris, gnome, citrix

I Cannot run compiled c program on solaris when in Citrix Desktop virtualization , I get this error:
`gnome-session: you're already running a session manager` 
But I can run from ssh clients. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to manually invoke `gnome-session`? There's an XY problem here, I can smell it. But it likely has nothing to do with programming...

Comment: Yesss!!, found a solution by changing my shell to `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

After much research and I found out that it worked by running it in `zsh` environment.